# animation on scroll function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I have a bunch of animations on the website, most of them activate on scroll into view, but somehow they wont work (and they used to), they activate when I refresh the page but not on scroll, here's a piece of the animations file, all the animations are pretty much the same only that targeted to different elements:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
   var top = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
       isVisible = top > $('.arqdiv h6').offset().top;
   $('.arqdiv h6').toggleClass('animated fadeInDown', isVisible);
});

$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
   var top = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
       isVisible = top > $('.arqdiv p').offset().top;
    $('.arqdiv p').toggleClass('animated fadeInDown', isVisible);
});




$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   var top = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
       isVisible = top > $('.staff').offset().top;
     $('.staff').toggleClass('animated fadeIn', isVisible);
});
```

in case the html or other files are needed to be seen this is the website im building http://www.inmobiliariagavilan.com

thanks!